# How to prove this question by Ramanujan?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

[click here for photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzSFI.png)
$$1+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{(4k)^3-(4k)}= \frac{3}{2}\ln(2)\,.$$

well i have attatched a photo which has been asked to prove without using calculus,but how to solve this using calculus ?

Comment: I don't see any photo....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sorry sir please hold on a second .

Comment: http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan's%20Notebooks%20I.pdf See page 39 (or page 29 ?) Indeed read chapter 2.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit thank you sir but is there any alternate proof ?

Comment: It is partial fractions, the technique is described in the ref.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit THANKS A LOT FOR THE BOOK SIR. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we have from partial fraction expansion

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{1}{(4k)^3-(4k)}&=\sum_{k=1}^{K}\left(-\frac1{4k}+\frac{1/2}{4k-1}+\frac{1/2}{4k+1}\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

Next, we make use of "ungrouping" even and odd terms of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^K\left(\frac{1}{4k+1}+\frac{1}{4k-1}\right)$ to write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^K\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{4k+1}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{4k-1}}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^K\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2\underbrace{(2k)}_{\text{even terms}}+1}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2\underbrace{(2k-1)}_{\text{odd terms}}+1}}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\frac1{2k+1}\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{1}{(4k)^3-(4k)}&=\frac12\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\color{purple}{\frac{1}{2k+1}}-\sum_{k=1}^{K}\color{orange}{\frac1{2k}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\left(\color{purple}{\frac{1}{2k+1}}-\color{orange}{\frac1{2k}}\right)+\frac12\sum_{k=K+1}^{2K}\color{orange}{\frac1{2k}}\tag3
\end{align}$$

We can proceed two distinct ways to continue from $(3)$.  The first relies on the [power series definition of the logarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Series) while the second relies on [the integral definition of the logarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Definitions) and [Riemann Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Connection_with_integration).

---

> **METODOLOGY $1$:  Using only $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=\log(2)\tag4$**

Here, we note that the general terms of the first summation on the right-hand side of $(3)$ is a grouping of the difference of successive even and odd reciprocal integers.  Hence, we can be expressed that summation as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac1{2k}\right)=\sum_{k=2}^{4K+1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\tag5$$

Using the result in $(5)$, the second summation on the right-hand side of $(3)$ can be written as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=K+1}^{2K}\frac1{2k}&=\frac12\sum_{k=K+1}^{2K}\frac1k\\\\
&=\frac12 \color{magenta}{\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\frac1k} -\frac12\sum_{k=1}^K\frac1k\\\\
&=\frac12 \color{magenta}{\sum_{k=1}^K \left(\frac1{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\right)}-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^K\frac1k\\\\
&=\frac12 \sum_{k=1}^K \left(\frac1{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\tag6
\end{align}$$

Substitution of $(5)$ and $(6)$ into $(3)$, letting $K\to \infty$, and exploiting $(4)$ yields the coveted result

$$\begin{align}
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4k)^3-(4k)}=\frac34\log(2)-\frac12}
\end{align}$$

---

> **METODOLOGY $2$:  Using only [Riemann Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum)**

Here, we write the firsts summation on the right-hand side of $(3)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac1{2k}\right)&=\color{aqua}{\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac1{2k}\right)}-\color{fuchsia}{2\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\frac1{2k}}\\\\
&=\color{aqua}{\sum_{k=2}^{4K+1}\frac1k}-\color{fuchsia}{\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\frac1{k}}\\\\
&=-1+\sum_{k=2K+1}^{4K+1}\frac1k\\\\
&=-1+\sum_{k=1}^{2K+1}\frac{1}{k+2K}\\\\
&=-1+\frac1K\sum_{k=1}^{2K+1}\frac{1}{2+(k/K)}\tag7
\end{align}$$

Similarly, we can write the second summation on the right-hand side of $(3)$ as

$$\sum_{k=K+1}^{2K}=\frac12 \frac1K\sum_{k=1}^K\frac{1}{1+(k/K)}\tag8$$

Substituting $(7)$ and $(8)$ into $(3)$ reveals

$$\sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{1}{(4k)^3-(4k)}=\frac12\left(-1+\frac1K\sum_{k=1}^{2K+1}\frac{1}{2+(k/K)} +\frac12 \frac1K\sum_{k=1}^K\frac{1}{1+(k/K)}\right)\tag9$$

Recognizing that the first summation on the right-hand side of $(9)$ is a Riemann Sum for $\int_0^2 \frac{1}{2+x}\,dx=\log(2)$ and that the second summation on the right-hand side of $(9)$ is a Riemann Sum for $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx=\log(2)$, we obtain upon letting $K\to \infty$

$$\begin{align}
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4k)^3-(4k)}=\frac34\log(2)-\frac12}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: I've added some links to references.

Comment: +1 for details along with explanation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Hi Paramanand!  How are you my friend?  I haven't seen you here for a while.

Comment: Yeah these days I am spending less time on MSE due to certain personal commitments. But like before I enjoy reading your answers.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh me bhi bharat se hun aapko MSE pe dekh ke acha lagaa

Comment: @MarkViola if you dont mind,can you give me an adivce ?

Comment: @NewBornMATH Tell me the advice you seek.

Comment: @MarkViola i'm 16 & have passed out my highschool last week and i am quite intrested in complex integration,contours more over complex analysis,but i am actually feeling depressed as i'm not able to grasp so much.When i ask my seniors to help me,they say,"what do u think,u can master everything in this class,you have to go the most natural path i.e. to complete your bachelors."but i have now a month before getting into a college.with due respect sir,could you please tell me(advice me) where should i start ?

Comment: Before you study complex analysis, I suggest that you study real analysis/advanced calculus.  There are many theorems used in complex analysis that generalize their counterparts in real analysis.  And topics such as uniform convergence will be of paramount importance in studying complex analysis.

Comment: @MarkViola thank you so much sir.with due respect sir,requesting for one last help.how to solve this                                                                   ABC is an isoceles triangle inscribed in a circle of radius $r$.If AB=AC and $h$ is the altitude from A to BC and $p$ be the perimiter of ABC then $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\Delta}{p^3}$$ (where $\Delta$ is the area of triangle )

Answer (score 2):

I have no clue how to solve this without calculus.  At least, I do not know how to define the natural logarithm without calculus.  I am borrowing some part of this solution from mechanodroid's deleted solution.

First, write
$$\frac{1}{(4k)^3-(4k)}=-\frac{1}{4k}+\frac{1}{2(4k-1)}+\frac{1}{2(4k+1)}$$
for every positive integer $k$.  Define
$$S_n:=1+2\,\sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{1}{(4k)^3-(4k)}$$
for all $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.  Hence, the $n$-th partial sum is given by $$
\begin{align}
S_{n}&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\,\left(-\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{4k-1}+\frac{1}{4k+1}\right)
\\&=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\ldots-\frac{1}{2n}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)
\\&=T_n+U_n\,,
\end{align}$$
where $T_n:=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\ldots-\frac{1}{2n}$ and $U_n:=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{4n+1}$.  It remains to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\,T_n=\ln(2)\text{ and }\lim_{n\to\infty}\,U_n=\frac{1}{2}\,\ln(2)\,.$$
The former is well known, whilst the latter follows from the fact that $2U_n$ is a Riemann sum for $\int_{2}^{4}\,\frac{1}{x}\,\text{d}x$.  Alternatively, observe that $T_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}$, and
$$\frac{1}{2} \,T_{n+1}\leq U_n\leq \frac{1}{2} T_{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{4n+2}\,.$$